# Cannot get a linefeed AND bold to work in a HTML button

Tags: html, telerik

I just want to add a line break and then make the second line bold inside a button.
The button happens to be a telerik Kendo button, but I don't think that is the problem.
I have tried both bold and strong.

```
                    <kendo-button name="printTrue" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlagsRefresh(true)">Set Print<br /><b>TRUE</b></kendo-button>
                <kendo-button name="printFalse" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlagsRefresh(false)">Set Print<br />FALSE</kendo-button>
```

I can get bold OR I can get a line feed....but not both!

[image]

The full code for that div is as follows:

```
                <div class="col-10 text-center" style="border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-width: thin;">
                <b>Action Buttons --==></b>
                <kendo-button name="printTrue" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlagsRefresh(true)">Set Print<b>TRUE</b></kendo-button>
                <kendo-button name="printFalse" type="button" onclick="FlipAllPrintFlagsRefresh(false)">Set Print<br />FALSE</kendo-button>
                <kendo-button name="markComplete" type="button" onclick="markComplete(true)">Complete: True</kendo-button>
                <kendo-button name="markNotComplete" type="button" onclick="markComplete(false)">Complete: False</kendo-button>
                <kendo-button name="resetCheckDate" type="button" onclick="resetCheckDate()">Reset Chck Date &Aacute; Num To Blank</kendo-button>
                @*<kendo-button name="docolors" type="button" onClick="ChangeColors()">colors test</kendo-button>*@

            </div>
```

the CSS for the buttons is simple so far:

```
    .k-button {
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #f26730;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Kendo adds `display: flex` to their buttons which prevents the line-break. You can add `    flex-direction: column;` to the button and it will split it into 2 lines without the need for a `<br/>`.

Comment: but the line break clearly works if I do not use the bold?

Comment: Yes because you don't have 2 elements so flex doesn't align them.

Comment: also, with flex-direction how do I tell it 'where' to break?

Comment: You tell it where to break with the second element (in your case the b tag)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to code that....if you want to write it up quickly as a answer I can test right away and accept.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: asp.net core / c# / using visual studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233042/discussion-between-jheth-and-joe-ruder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo adds `display: flex` to it's buttons which will cause multiple elements (the b tag in this case) to align horizontally. Adding `flex-direction: column` to your `.k-button` class and keeping the b tag will make b tag be positioned below the rest of the button's inner HTML content. You can even remove the line-break since it is no longer needed.

But be sure to add this through an additional class or ID so it does not affect all your buttons.